# Google Pay SDK check if user has already added specific card

Tags: android, kotlin, google-pay

Does **Google Pay API** have a method for checking if the user has already added a specific card into **Google Pay**? I know that there exists a method for checking if the user available make payments.

> [From official docs:](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/tutorial#paymentdatarequest)
>   ... call the isReadyToPay API to determine if the user can make payments with the Google Pay API.

```java
private void possiblyShowGooglePayButton() {
    final Optional<JSONObject> isReadyToPayJson = PaymentsUtil.getIsReadyToPayRequest();
    if (!isReadyToPayJson.isPresent()) {
      return;
    }
    IsReadyToPayRequest request = IsReadyToPayRequest.fromJson(isReadyToPayJson.get().toString());
    if (request == null) {
      return;
    }

    // The call to isReadyToPay is asynchronous and returns a Task. We need to provide an
    // OnCompleteListener to be triggered when the result of the call is known.
    Task<Boolean> task = mPaymentsClient.isReadyToPay(request);
    task.addOnCompleteListener(this,
        new OnCompleteListener<Boolean>() {
          @Override
          public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Boolean> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
              setGooglePayAvailable(task.getResult());
            } else {
              Log.w("isReadyToPay failed", task.getException());
            }
          }
        });
  }
```

But the code above  does not suites my needs. Maybe someone has a solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by a specific card?

One thing that is easy to miss from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/reference/request-objects#IsReadyToPayRequest) `existingPaymentMethodRequired`.

By default, the API checks whether or not the device/app can be used to make payments but passing the `existingPaymentMethodRequired` option will check to see if they have existing payment methods that the user can use to make a payment.

Comment: I mean that you have a screen with user data about his card, you need to check if the user has already added the card 4141 0000 0000 0000 into GPay to do some UI changes.

Comment: `existingPaymentMethodRequired` is also not what I want to use. It's checks availability to pay in general.

Comment: In that case, no. I don't believe any APIs exist for this: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library?supportedpurview=project&q=pay

Answer (score 0):

Check [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/pay/issuers/apis/push-provisioning/android/reading-wallet).

If you have access to the token reference ID (generated when the card was added, could be provided to you by the service provider), you can call `getTokenStatus`, which will return if the token is still active on the wallet of the user.

If the card was added by your application (same package name), `listTokens` will allow you to get all the tokens (cards) that were added, and you will be able to compare them with your specific card.

You can also use `isTokenized` if you have access to the card network and the service provider.

Do note that there is a small limitation : for the last two methods, the check is made based on the 4 last digits card. It is possible (but rare) for the same user to have 2 cards on the same network ending with the same 4 last digits.

Comment: I bet it's easier and more secure to do with their private lib - `TapAndPay`.